# Como criar getter de variavel Local Date?

Tags: java, android

Eu tenho uma classe chamada `Hospede`, onde possuo o método `getData_entrada()`, que retorna uma variável `LocalDate`(nova API java8). Porém, quando tento capturar este método, ele me retorna sempre '`null`'.

Detalhe: quando tento capturar os outros getters funciona normalmente.

```
//conteudo getData_entrada:

public LocalDate getData_entrada() {

        return data_entrada;
   }



     Hospede hospede = (Hospede) mStrings.get(position);

     textView_nome.setText(hospede.getNome());

     LocalDate data_Entrada = hospede.getData_entrada();
```

Comment: Tem como você colocar o conteúdo do `getData_entrada()` na pergunta?

Comment: public LocalDate getData_entrada() {
        return data_entrada;
    }

Comment: Ha varias formas de como resolver esse problema, nos explique melhor o contexto do seu aplicativo para que possamos lhe ajudar com a melhor opção.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode definir o `getData_entrada()` desta forma abaixo:

```
public LocalDate getData_entrada() {
    return LocalDate.now();
}
```

Veja os métodos estáticos da classe pública [**`LocalDate`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.htm) para obtenção da hora atual:

- [now()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#now--): Obtém a data atual do relógio do sistema no fuso horário padrão.
- [now(Clock clock)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html): Obtém a data atual do relógio especificado.
- [now(ZoneId zone)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html): Obtém a data atual do relógio do sistema no fuso horário especificado.

Veja mais detalhes [na documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html).